# Error al "pip install robotframework-selenium2library==1.8.0"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pip

para instalar la ultima versión de seleniumlibrary2 me da un error, ya segui todos los pasos de:
https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary/

Adjunto pantallazo del error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien me puede ayudar? Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

El problema es de compatibilidad

> Selenium2Library 1.8 supports Python 2.6-2.7.

Fuente [Selenium2Library](https://github.com/robotframework/Selenium2Library), también lo dicen en este [Issue](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/2677).

Y según veo en la captura de pantalla usted usa Python 3, ¡¿cierto?!

¿Por qué no intenta `pip install --upgrade robotframework-selenium2library`?

> El comando anterior instala SeleniumLibrary, así como una
> nueva versión de Selenium2Library que es solo un wrapper
> para SeleniumLibrary. Eso permite importar Selenium2Library en pruebas
> mientras se migra a SeleniumLibrary.

> A partir de la versión 3.0, Selenium2Library pasa a llamarse
> SeleniumLibrary y este proyecto (Selenium2Library) existe principalmente para ayudar con
> la transición.